# each day on scale with dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to display my data on a time scale that shows every day not only every second, like the default does.
I was tempering with d3.time.scale but there was no difference in the chart.

```
var scale = d3.time.scale();
scale.domain([new Date('2015-03-01'), new Date('2015-03-26')]);
...
var chart = dc.lineChart('#chart');
...
chart.x(scale);
chart.xUnits(d3.time.day);
```

Result: Tue 03, Thue 05, Sat 07, Mon 09, ...
Wanted Result: Tue 03, Wen 04, Thue 05, Fri 06, ...

even better: Mar 03rd, Mar 04th, Mar 05th, ...
Can this be done by `scale.tickFormat()` or do i have to use `chart.xAxis().tickFormat()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) then you can format the dates as Mar 03rd using `chart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) { return moment()... })`. There is a lot of documentation on moment, so that shouldn't take too much time to figure out. As for the display issue, you can use `chart.xAxis().tick([enter number of ticks here])`, however, that only gives dc.js a suggested number of ticks and may not necessarily output the number of ticks you input.